# NHIbernate SQLQuery and enum

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm trying to map an enum field to a dto property. I'm using PositionalToBeanResultTransformer, something like this:

```
PositionalToBeanResultTransformer trans = new PositionalToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(DTOClass), new string[] { "Id", "EnumProperty" });
var data = Sesion.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT Id, EnumField FROM Table")
        .AddScalar("EnumField", NHibernateUtil.Custom(typeof(Enumerador)))
        .SetResultTransformer(trans)
        .List<DTOClass>();

public class DTOClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Enumerador EnumProperty { get; set; }
}
```

the DTOClass is not mapped so I can't use AddEntity() and the code with AddScalar() throws an error that I must implement NHibernate.UserTypes.IUserType.
How can I convert the string field of the DB to an enum in a SQLQuery?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Are you using hbm or fluent for mapping.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using AutoMapping, in your ClassMap add a similar line like below:

```
Table("MyClass");
Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
Map(x => x.Type).CustomType(typeof(Enumerations.MyType));

public virtual int Id { get; set; }
public virtual Enumerations.MyType Type { get; set; }
```

I usually store my enums as integers in the DB and the ClassMap will appropriately map back to the enumeration.

Comment: The DTOClass is not mapped, that's why I'm using PositionalToBeanResultTransformer.